# “The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net

*javascript function*

```
function ShowVisit(ID)
    {
       //do something with ID
    }   
       <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterPatientList" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr id="objTR" runat="server" ondblclick="return ShowVisit('<%#Eval("ID") %>')">
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

When i give runat="server" to tr then error grows “The server tag is not well formed.” What's wrong?

Comment: why are you adding `id` inside `<tr>` remove the runat and id

Comment: What's the role of ShowVisit() and is it in the same file?

Comment: i have to access tr on server side in c#

Answer (score 3):

```
 <tr id="objTR" 
     runat="server" 
     ondblclick=<%# "return ShowVisit('" + Eval("ID") +  "');"  %>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ondblclick="return ShowVisit('<%#Eval("ID") %>')` this interpreted by compiler as 
 `ondblclick="return ShowVisit('<%#Eval("` as fist string
 `ID` as second 
`") %>')"` as third string.
It because your double qoute start from just before  return and end before ID MEANS ITS first string now there is no concatenation betwen first string and ID so it's error.Similarly for the sceond and thisd string.Your Above string is treated as same llike below..

`string str="Hello"id"How are you";`

To make it single string and to make work,,,
You can try like this...

```
 ondblclick='<%#@"return ShowVisit("""+ (Eval("ID") as string) +@""");" %>'
```

Comment: I tested it and says: The server tag is not well formed.